# Change background color of button after sent action (after one click)

Tags: html, ajax, forms

Hello I have a contact form I want to do it with PHP. And I have the submit button, I want when all fields are ready to press, when the email was send to change my button. First in my button is a text with background color yellow and the text is "Send". When I press the button and the email is sent I want to change the background color in red and I want to add an icon aside to text, the text is modifed in "Sent". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script >
 function button(){
    //your ajax code for sending data  
  /*  function retrieveData(){
        $.post('server.php',{}, function(data){ 
   });*/

   $("#button").attr('value', 'Sent');
   $("#button").css("background-color","red")
}
</script>

<input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="Send" onclick="button()">
```

Try this. You can do it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have a form with some inputs and a submit button.

You want to manipulate the submit button after all of the form fields were filled-in, and finally manipulate it again once the submit button was clicked.

What you need to do is to write a little javascript (either plain vanilla or jQuery, choose what suits you best) to handle two things in your form

1. Your form's input fields (for first submit button change):
     Attach an event to the input fields to check for validation as you   wish, and change the submit button accordingly.
2. Your form's submit button (for the second submit button change):
       Attach a click event to the submit button (and make sure to prevent the default, so once the submit button was clicked, it will be manipulated in the way you wish.

I have wrote you an example, where in my scenario I have two input in my form and a submit button which is disabled and greyed-out by default.
As soon as all form fields are filled-in (not empty), the submit button becomes active (disable attribute removed and color change) - finally when the submit button is being clicked, it will change it's color to green as an indication that it was clicked.

```
$('#myForm input').on('keyup',function(){
    var validated = true;
    $('#myForm input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === ''){
        validated = false;
    }
    });
    if(validated){
      $('#submitBtn').removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled',false);
    }else{
      $('#submitBtn').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});

$('#submitBtn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).addClass('submited').prop('disabled',true);

    // the rest of your code for submission..
 });
```

**Here's the simple fully working example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/wx9gonrh/

Of course you can use this example and modify it to your own needs, or write your own from scratch using this as guidance.

In your case you might want to incorporate an async method for changing the submit button only after the emails were successfully sent (e.g. an ajax complete\done event)

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's what I want but what happens when I submit the form? The form has an "action" for sending the data

Comment: When attaching an event to something like a submit action, you need to be in charge - that means that after you do your custom code (in this case - changing the background color of the button on submit) you need to programmatically initiate the submit action of the form, for an example:
`$('#myForm').submit()` with jQuery

Comment: I am sorry but I think that you misunderstand this: when you are submitting a form from a client (in this case a form in a web browser), it is not being done by PHP ( a server-side language), it is being done by your browser by either submitting it with javascript, ajax request, or the traditional submit which will POST the form data to the form action defined - the PHP on the other end (the server) is the receiving side, which receives the data posted from the client and process it